# How to Clone an Attribute Set

Tags: attribute-set

Is there was a way to programmatically clone an attribute set? I would like to create a new attribute set based on the DEFAULT set. I would like my cloned new attribute set to contain all the same groups and attributes that the Default set does.

I thought there was a way to quickly write a program to do this, but now I'm getting confused.

Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

```
$entityTypeId      = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
$baseAttributeSet  =  4; // "default" attribute set 
$model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
            ->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);
$model->setAttributeSetName('my_attr_set');
$model->validate();
$model->save();
$model->initFromSkeleton($baseAttributeSet);
$model->save();
```

Code extract from `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_SetController::saveAction()`